# redux mapStateToProps call ajax incase of empty state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

Using `redux` in `react`, how can I dispatch an action from inside the `mapStateToProps` function ?

```jsx
class Example React.Component {
  render(){return (
    <div>
      Hello {this.state.userData.name} <--
    </div>)};
);

Example.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

function select(state,ownProps) {
  let userData = state.user[ownProps.id];
  if(!userData){//if not already in store then i want to load it
    ///I WANT TO dispatch an action that load this user from server.
    //dispatch({type:'LOAD_USER',id: ownProps.id});
  }
  return {
    userData
  };
}

export default connect(select)(Example);

//example usage <Example id="1" /> //should return state.user[1].name
```

Comment: dispatch it from `componentDidMount` or `componentWillReceiveProps` instead

Comment: @Deadfish valid point.. stupid me ! thanks i'm wondering if i should delete the post and hide in shame now ! #mental_block

Answer (score 0):

Since your component rendering is very dependent on the user data being called by ajax, the right place to dispatch would be `componentWillReceiveProps`.

If you have passed in a `mapDispatchToProps` callback to `connect()`, then you should be able to call `this.props.actions.anyAction()` within `componentWillReceiveProps`.

If you had called `connect()` without passing in the second parameter (`mapDispatchToProps`), then you'll have to explicitly call `this.props.dispatch()`

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend to use sagas for asynchronous tasks.
Have a saga watch for this action.
If it sees one, let it check if the user is in store.
If he is not in store, make an asynchronous action to get it, add it to the store, and replay the previous action.